# DNS wildcard and /etc/resolv.conf problem

Tags: wildcard-subdomain, resolv.conf

I searched through google.com but can't find an answer... So I asked here.

This is the problem:

I build a DNS test environment on my PC which hostname is `gamepc`.

The DNS server (bind9) has a wildcard record:

```
* IN A 192.168.0.1
```

And the /etc/resolv.conf file has a entry:

```
domain bogus.
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

So when I ping `somehost` it will return like:

```
PING somehost.bogus (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from gamepc.bogus (192.168.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
...
```

And when I ping `google.com` it will return like:

```
PING google.com (74.125.71.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hx-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.71.99): icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=68.0 ms
...
```

So far everything is good. But if I ping some non-exist domain e.g. `sldfjsldjflksdjf.com` it will still return like:

```
PING sldfjsldjflksdjf.com.bogus (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from gamepc.bogus (192.168.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
...
```

And the expected result should be:

```
ping: unknown host sldfjslkdfjlksdjfklsdjf.com
```

I can thought how this happened. At first the resolver try `sldfjslkdfjlksdjfklsdjf.com` but get a `NXDOMAIN` response.  Then it append the domain part and try `sldfjslkdfjlksdjfklsdjf.com.bogus` again. This time the host name match the wildcard record in DNS server and return `192.168.0.1` ...

Does anyone have the same issue? And how did you resolve it?

Thank you very much for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have the same issue?

Everyone has the issue.  It's *a standard part* of most DNS client libraries.  It's variously called a *domain search path* or *DNS search path* or [*DNS devolution*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee683928%28WS.10%29.aspx).

> And how did you resolve it?

By using [fully-qualified domain names](http://menandmice.com/online_docs_and_faq/glossary/fqdn.htm) where I desire them.  You are *not* using FQDNs.

> the browser don't use FQDN to resolve host domain name

This is your first mention of a WWW browser.  You didn't mention it in the question.  WWW browsers are oddities, not least because they have two, sometimes more, domain search paths operating one on top of another.  [People **do** use fully qualified domain names in URLs for precisely this reason.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-fully-qualified-domain-name.html)  If you're going to set up your DNS client library such that its search path mechanism successfully maps names to addresses like this, you're going to have to do so as well.  This is the consequence of your choosing to have a search path and a wildcard that matches everything in an entire subtree.  [*One has to **think** about using wildcards.*](http://iab.org/documents/correspondence-reports-documents/docs2003/2003-09-20-dns-wildcards/)

Comment: Yes. If I use FQDN (ending with trailing dot) then the returned result is the desired one. (`NXDOMAIN`) But the problem is that the browser don't use FQDN to resolve host domain name... I mean when I type in `_non-exist-domain_.com` in browser address bar then it will visit `192.168.0.1`. Of course I can type `_non-exist-domain_.com.` (trailing dot) then it will return correct result (could not find host). But people don't type the trailing dot normally I think...

Comment: Thank you all! Although this problem is not resolved I have a better understanding in DNS and resolve.conf now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From `man resolv.conf`:

```
domain Local domain name.
   Most  queries  for names within this domain can use short names relative 
   to the local domain. If no domain entry is present, the domain is 
   determined from the local hostname returned by gethostname(2); the domain 
   part is taken to be everything after the first '.'.  Finally, if the 
   hostname does not contain a domain part, the root domain is assumed.

search Search list for host-name lookup.
   The search list is normally determined from the local domain name; 
   by default, it  contains  only the  local  domain name. (...)
```

So, if you query for `sldfjslkdfjlksdjfklsdjf` then bind finds no matching record, so your resolver tries `sldfjslkdfjlksdjfklsdjf.bogus`, which in turn returns an address.

If you ping `sldfjslkdfjlksdjfklsdjf.` (note the trailing dot) you should be OK (i.e. the lookup will fail). The trailing dot means that you supplied a FQDN of the host, so no domain suffixes should be tried.

Comment: Yes. If I use FQDN (ending with trailing dot) then the returned result is the desired one. (`NXDOMAIN`) But the problem is that the browser don't use FQDN to resolve host domain name... I mean when I type in `_non-exist-domain_.com` in browser address bar then it will visit `192.168.0.1`. Of course I can type `_non-exist-domain_.com.` (trailing dot) then it will return correct result (could not find host). But people don't type the trailing dot normally I think...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think u can actually resolve the issue due to the fact that u have the wildcard in your DNS configuration.

When not using the wildcard u will get the error message, but with the wildcard and your resolv.conf options everything unknown will resolve to your domain.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Yes, that's where the problem lie. If I remove the `domain` entry in `/etc/resolv.conf` then it will be working normally. But I want the convenient of ping `somehost` will ping `somehost.bogus`. Are there some method to only append domain part to hostname which not contain a dot so ping `sdjflksjdflksjdf.com` will **not** ping `sdjflksjdflksjdf.com.bogus`?